# Bulk api Load limitations

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud

Could some one help me out by sharing the limitations we have while loading data using Bulk mode API. As in IOP we cannot use bulk mode data loading when the target table has constraints on it. DO we have similar limitation in IOD as well?

We have a performance issues while loading data into salesforce objects using IOD. One approach I was thinking to load data in Bulk Api load, but wanted to know if there are any limitations.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly API limitations - it's the consequence of using Bulk Load. One solution applicable in SOME situations is:

- drop the constraints (FKs, indexes)
- do the bulk load
- recreate constraints (create indexes, create FKs)

Comment: drooping and re-creating indexes on salesforce objects is not realistic that we can do in case of oracle tables. We have a salesforce object as a target here. I did tried bulk api mode with all keys and constraint enabled and it was completed smoothly. So i just wanted to know is it fine to use bulk mode with all constraints and keys enabled/??

Comment: It's not fine, I'm afraid. Indexes will not be properly updated. Please verify this as I haven't done this with Salesforce, however.